# Surface View not working

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-debug

I am trying to set up a surface view for graphics but an error keeps showing up that I have to import SView when I already did. Everything I try never seems to work. Is anything missing in the following code? or is it that I forgot to add something.

Firstclass.java:

```
package com.XXX.XXX;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.mtprogramming.blockfight.SView;

SView ourView;
 public class Singleplayer extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourView = new SView(this);
    setContentView(ourView);

}




}
```

SView:

```
package com.XXX.XXX;

public class SView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

public SView(Singleplayer singleplayer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void run(){

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the package for `SView.java`: `com.XXX.XXX` it intended as so?

If yes, use `import com.XXX.XXX.Sview` instead of `import com.mtprogramming.blockfight.SView` in `Firstclass.java`